# Do I have to explicitly reference an implicit dependency of a package I want to use?

Tags: .net, .net-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`, which depends on `MySqlConnector`.
I have not explicitly referenced `MySqlConnector` in my `.csproj` file and the project seems to compile and run fine.

However, I am unsure if there are any drawbacks to not referencing `MySqlConnector` explicitly from my project?

My project is a .NET 5.0 desktop app using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

The `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` package automatically references `MySqlConnector` implicitly, because it depends on it.

So as long as you don't want to use any specific ADO.NET `MySqlConnector` functionality (like `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand` or `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`) in your code and only want to use EF Core, there is no need to reference the package explicitly.

If your project needs to explicitly reference `MySqlConnector`, you would get a compile-time error that would tell you so. Therefore unless you got such an error, everything is fine.

A simple way to verify that the library is indeed being used, is to look in your `.\bin\Debug` directory, where the `MySqlConnector.dll` should be after you compiled your project. But again, if your projects uses `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` and has been successfully compiled, that is already prove enough.